# SXA indexes are populated with limited document count only

Tags: solr, indexing, index

I am facing a weird issue like if I index `sitecore_sxa_master_index` and `sitecore_sxa_web_index` then popup shows all items indexed successfully and no error is coming in either siteore logs or SOLR logs.

[image]

But when I see the SOLR portal for the sxa master and sxa web index then only 39 docs are being pushed (screenshot below), but all other indexes are working fine.

[image]

Do you have any idea that what could be the issue?

Comment: If you check `showconfig` what is root path for both of them? And what is `core` name for both of them?

Comment: Did you check if any crawler is added in the configuration and what the Root points to?

Comment: Will update the answer here we are connecting with Sitecore support team for this issue.